# PHP - I need to initiate a class that optimises images within a loop so that each image will be optimised as it is uploaded?

Tags: php

---

### Upload php file

I am trying to create a new instance of a class that will optimize an image on upload within a for loop however it will only run through the class once optimize one image perfectly and then fail for the next image and then the loop exits after that. When the class is initiated it requires a parameter of the filename so it needs to be initiated within the a loop.

```
    // Set the date variable to current date
    $date = new DateTime();
    // Format date into year/month/day
    $date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    // Create storage array variable
    $storage = array();

    //Check if image file is an actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["uploadImage"])) {
      // Variable for target directory
      $target_dir = "uploads/";

      // Set uploadOk variable to true
      $uploadOk = 1;

    // Count number of files uploaded
    $countFiles = count($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);


    // Loop through each file
    for ($i = 0; $i < $countFiles; $i++) {
      // Variable for taget file - specifies the path of the file to be uploaded
      $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]);

      // Variable for file type - holds the extension type of the file
      $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));


      if (empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$i])) {
        echo 'error no file has been selected';
        exit();
      }

        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i]);
        if ($check !== false) {
          echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
          $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
          echo "File is not an image";
          $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        // Check if the file already exists
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
          echo "Sorry, file already exists";
          $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        // Check and limit the file size
        if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"][$i] > 100000000) {
          echo "Sorry, your file is too large";
          $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        // Allow certain file formats
        if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" &&                 
        $imageFileType !="gif") {
          echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed";
          $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
          echo "Sorry, your file has not been uploaded";
          // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
          // Query to check the number of rows
          $results = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS numRows FROM tbl" . $_SESSION['username'] . 
    "Photos");
          // Insert results into variable
          $numRows = $results->fetchColumn();
          // Check if the table is empty
          if ($numRows == 0) {
            // Set image number
            $id = 1;
            // Set the new file name to IMG_1
            $newFileName = "IMG_" . $id;
          } else {
            // Find the id of the latest row in table
            $results = $pdo->query("SELECT MAX(id) as max FROM tbl" . $_SESSION['username'] . 
    "Photos");
            // Insert results into table
            $maxId = $results->fetchColumn();
            // Increment id
            $maxId = $maxId + 1;
            // Set file name to IMG_id
            $newFileName = "IMG_" . $maxId;
          }

          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_dir . 
    $newFileName . '.' . $imageFileType)) {
            //echo "The file" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]) . " has been uploaded";
            addPhotoSQL($pdo, $newFileName, $target_dir, $imageFileType, $date);
            // Add data to storage array
            array_push($storage, $target_dir . $newFileName . '.' . $imageFileType);
            //Resize image
            include_once('Class Library/clsResize.php');
            $resizeObj[$i] = new resize($storage[$i]);
            $resizeObj[$i]->resizeImage(300, 300, 'auto');
            $resizeObj[$i]->saveImage($storage[$i], 1000);
          }
          else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading this file";
          }
        }
      }
    exit();
    }
```

---

### Optimize Image class

```
    class resize {
      // Private class variables
      private $image;
      private $width;
      private $height;
      private $imageResized;

      function __construct($fileName) {
        // Open the file
        $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName);
        // Get the height and width
        $this->width = imagesx($this->image);
        $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
      }

      private function openImage($file) {
        // Get file extension
        $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

        switch($extension) {
          case '.jpg':
          case '.jpeg':
            $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
          case '.gif':
            $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
            break;
          case '.png':
            $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
            break;
          default:
            $img = false;
            break;
        }
        return $img;
      }


      public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto") {
        // Get the optimal width and height based on auto
        $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

        $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];

        // Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
        $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth,         
    $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);

        // If option is crop, then crop too
        if ($option == 'crop') {
          $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
        }
      }

      private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option) {
        switch($option) {
          case 'exact':
            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
            $optimalHeight = $newHeight;
            break;
          case 'portrait':
            $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
            $optimalHeight = $newHeight;
            break;
          case 'landscape':
            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
            $optimalHeight = $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
            break;
          case 'auto':
            $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
            $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
            break;
          case 'crop':
            $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
            $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
            break;
        }
        return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
      }

      private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight) {
        $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
        $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;

        return $newWidth;
      }

      private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth) {
        $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
        $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;

        return $newHeight;
      }

      private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight) {
        // If image to be resized is landscape
        if ($this->height < $this->width) {
          $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
          $optimalHeight = $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
        }
        // If image is portrait
        else if ($this->height > $this->width) {
          $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
          $optimalHeight = $newHeight;
        }
        else {
          if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
            $optimalHeight = $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
          } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
            $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
            $optimalHeight = $newHeight;
          } else {
            // Square being resized to a square
            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
            $optimalHeight = $newHeight;
          }
        }
        return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
      }



      private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight) {
          $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
          $widthRatio = $this->width / $newWidth;

          if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
            $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
          } else {
            $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
          }

          $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
          $optimalWidth = $this->width / $optimalRatio;

          return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
        }


          private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight) {
            // Find center, will be used for crop
            $cropStartX = ($optimalWidth / 2) - ($optimalHeight / 2);
            $cropStartY = ($optimalHeight / 2) - ($optimalWidth / 2);

            $crop = $this->imageResized;

            // Now crop from center to exact requested size
            $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
            imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop, 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth,         
            $newHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
          }

          public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100") {
            // Get extension
            $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
            $extension = strtolower($extension);

            switch($extension) {
              case '.jpg':
              case '.jpeg':
                if (imagetypes() && IMG_JPG) {
                  imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                }
                break;
              case '.gif':
                if (imagetypes() && IMG_GIF) {
                  imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
                }
                break;
              case '.png':
                // Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
                $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

                // Invert quality setting to 0 is best, not 9
                $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

                if (imagetypes() && IMG_PNG) {
                  imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                }
                break;
                default:
                  break;
            }

            imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
          }
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong exactly? What "fails" means to you?

Comment: So when the code is run for example if I were uploading 3 images the first one will be optimized/resized and uploaded, the second image is not optimized at all but is still uploaded, then the script cuts out and stops working so the next image is not uploaded at all.

Comment: Cuts out where? Start debugging your code to understand why it's stopping working. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I have no errors, it cuts out where I am initiating the new class at the - //Resize image - section